# how to call a function in codeigniter email library

Tags: codeigniter

i am using codeigniter framework. i am calling a function from controller to custome library. i want to call another function in that function.i am calling below calendarupdate() function in emailcom library.Please help me. I am trying like below.

```
         function calendarupdate($info, $users)
        {
        $this->subject="Calendar Schedule Update";
        $this->to='test@gmail.com';
        $this->CI->email->from('support@gmail.com','test'); 
        $this->CI->email->to($this->to);
        $this->CI->email->subject($this->subject);
        $this->CI->email->message('Hi');
        $this->CI->email->set_mailtype("html");
         if($this->CI->email->send())
         {
            $this->CI->email->clear(TRUE);
            $this->newadmin($info,$newarr,$adminusers); 
         }}
```

I need to call newadmin() funtion in Emailcom library only.

Comment: In your library, have you setup $this->CI instance?

Comment: Yes, I have declare

Answer (score 0):

If the second method you need to call is also in the `emailcomm` class, simply use `$this->newadmin()`

Comment: I tried,i have declared in emailcom function but it is not working.Please tell me where to declare.

Comment: I'd need to see some code to get a better picture of what you've built so far